# One sided ping on VM

Tags: virtual-machine, ping

I have my PC (Windows 7) and a Virtual machine running on it with VM Player (Windows XP).

I have a server running Windows 7 and virtual machine with Windows XP and oracle instances.

PC - 192.168.1.18
PC VM - 192.168.1.9

Server - 192.168.1.12
Server VM - 192.168.1.13

On the VM Configuration Network adapters they all set to: Bridged.

My ping problem is that I **cannot** ping the Server VM from PC VM.
i can ping the Server VM from the other computers, and what is odd i can ping the PC VM from server VM (one sided ping).

This used to work, the only thing i added lately was a new user on that server and that user is logged in also.

What has gone wrong?